# mysql left join and union?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this left join query to show all job listings to employees who are in an asigned group of a particular supervisor, it works great

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs j 
LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.group_number = j.relevant_group 
WHERE j.relevant_group = 0 
OR (g.supervisor_id = j.job_lister_id AND g.employee_id = '$myVar')
```

But, now I need to add in a selection so that the posting supervisor can see it also, I set up the $ myVar to hold the session id of the viewer. I tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs j 
LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.group_number = j.relevant_group 
WHERE j.relevant_group = 0 
OR (g.supervisor_id = j.job_lister_id AND g.employee_id = '$myVar')
OR (j.job_lister_id = '$myVar')
```

But when the supervisor logs in he sees the listing posted numerous times (the duplication amount always equals the number of people in the group)
how do i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need any fields from `groups` to be in the result set? Because it sounds like you're just using `groups` to identify which `jobs` records to return? If that's the case, then you should probably dispense with the `JOIN`, and use a subquery instead. For example, you might write:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM jobs j
 WHERE j.job_lister_id = '$myVar'
    OR j.relevant_group = 0
    OR EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM groups g
           WHERE g.group_number = j.relevant_group
             AND g.supervisor_id = j.job_lister_id
             AND g.employee_id = '$myVar'
        )
;
```